# Given sum of 4 variables as a constant, how to maximize the sum of products?

Tags: calculus, inequality, optimization, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, maximum-principle

If variables a, b, c, and d are positive numbers and
a + b + c + d = 1,

Can I find the maximum of the expression below?

ab + cd

and how can I reach that?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: 1. fix $a+b$, what is maximum possible value of $ab$? 2. fix $c+d$, what is maximum possible value of $cd$. 3) treat $\lambda = a+b$ as a variable, then $c+d = 1-\lambda$, optimize the sum of result in (1) and (2) as a function in $\lambda$.

Comment: Well, I tried that method, but I realized that I have no way to show two situations of being equal can happen in same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:$${(a+b+c+d)}^2-4ab-4cd={(a-b)}^2+{(c-d)}^2+2(ac+bd+ad+bc)\ge 0$$

Comment: Oh so the square of (a+b+c+d) is the maximum, but how can I demonstrate that the maximum value is same as square of (a+b+c+d)?

Comment: @서정민 notice $a+b+c+d$=1

Comment: @서정민 Put some thought into it. If you already did, then share what you're done and where you're stuck, instead of just saying that you're stuck and hoping everyone knows exactly what you're thinking about.

Comment: @CalvinLin Alright. Thanks a lot for your help! I'll find ways to contribute

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $ab+cd \leq (a+c)(b+d)$.

Comment: You clarified my mind.. Thank you!!

Comment: Hmm... I found that I cannot show the equality ab+cd = (a+c)(b+d) can happen

Comment: Can you get arbitrarily close? If so, you're found the supremum (though not the maximum as it can't be achieved).